# ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python

I want to change the contents in a list of tuples, returned by a findall() function. And I am not sure whether I could change the elements from string to integer like this. And the error always shows that I need more than 1 value.

```
Ntuple=[]

match = re.findall(r'AnswerCount="(\d+)"\s*CommentCount="(\d+)"', x)

print match

for tuples in match:
    for posts, comments in tuples:
        posts, comments = int(posts), (int(posts)+int(comments))  ## <- error

print match
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the line `for posts, comments in tuples:`. Here `tuples` is actually a single tuple containing two strings, so there is no need to iterate over it. You probably want something like:

```
matches = re.findall(...)
for posts, comments in matches:
    ....
```

Comment: @ interjay: yes, thank you. I thought the element of the list is tuple, and the element of the tuple is the two 'posts' and 'comments'  thus I wrote two for loop. It seems that one single tuple cannot interative in a for loop. And that is why it appears an error. Am I correct? :)

Comment: @user942891: You can iterate over a tuple, but then you'd get the strings one at a time. What you want here is to get both strings at the same time, so that you can assign them to both the `posts` and `comments` variable. When you assign to multiple variables like that, the tuple will be unpacked automatically so there's no need to iterate over it.

Comment: @ interjay: Thanks. This time, I got it. And morevoer, I still have problems to assignment. Why  'posts, comments = int(posts), (int(posts)+int(comments))' didn't change the list of tuple at all?? I really appreciate your help. :)

Comment: @AnneS: That line only changes the values of the variables `posts` and `comments`. If you want to change the list you will have to update its elements. I would create a new list instead, for example by using a list comprehension: `newList = [(int(posts), int(posts)+int(comments)) for posts, comments in matches]`

Answer (score 1):

`match` is a list of tuples. The correct way of iterating over it is:

```
  matches = re.findall(r'AnswerCount="(\d+)"\s*CommentCount="(\d+)"', x)
  for posts, comments in matches:
    posts, comments = int(posts), (int(posts)+int(comments))
```

The conversion from string to integer is fine.

Comment: `for tuples in match` is correct because match is the return value of `re.findall` (i.e. a list). Though it is confusingly named.

Comment: Yes, this time, no error appears. But when I print the new matches to see the changes for the tuples, it is still remain the same. Why didn't my tuple assignment work at all?